# Mysterious ORA-06553: PLS-103

Tags: plsql

I have a very strange problem in handling of a PLSQL package.

We have the same package and body in two environments PRODUCTION and TEST. The one on PRODUCTION compiles with no issues but on TEST it throws this error

```
Error: 
ORA-06553: PLS-103: Encountered the symbol "ALTERNATIV_NAME" when expecting one of the following:
     <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> 
ORA-06553: PLS-112: end-of-line in quoted identifier".
```

I have copied the same package structure with the body from PRODUCTION to TEST database, but still I get the same. The body throws the above mentioned error.

I am unable to understand what is 'ALTERNATIV_NAME', any help is much appreciated.

Comment: how you are compiling your code in test env and prod env. Are you using sql plus for this?

Comment: try to set sqlbl on; and then try to deploy the code if you are using sql plus for deployment

Comment: search for the text ALTERNATIVE_NAME in your package. There's maybe an object with that name in production environment but it wasn't created in the testing environment

Comment: @pablomatico I am using sql developer tool to compile the package Right click--> compile. Then I get this error. It's very strange the same package (PRODUCTION) compiles without any errors. The one on TEST gives this strange error. Following queries didn't give any output. select * from user_source where upper(text) like ('%ALTERNATIV_NAME%'); select * from user_tab_cols where upper(column_name) like ('%ALTERNATIV_NAME%'); select * from user_objects where upper(OBJECT_NAME) like '%ALTERNATIV_NAME%'; The package also doesn't have anything with 'ALTERNATIV_NAME'

Comment: `ORA-06553: PLS-112: end-of-line in quoted identifier"`It seems like there's some missquoted literal

Answer (score 0):

The error is a syntax error.  There's something in the source code which is breaking compilation.  The error message should include line numbers which will point you to the spot to look at.

Questions in the form 'my code runs in environment A but fails in environment B' are virtually impossible for us to answer.  Even if you posted your code the chances are we still won't be able to help, because the most likely cause is some difference between the two environments, and obviously we don't have access to them.

The good news is, you do have access to your two environments and so you can figure out what is different between the two.  For instance, one possible explanation is a non-printing character in the script which is ignored in one environment but hurls in the other because they're on different operating systems.

Incidentally, this suggests you have a problem in your deployment process.  You shouldn't have anything in PRODUCTION which hasn't been run successfully in TEST.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late, but maybe help someone.

I had same issue, it appears that inside the PL/SQL code , i was referencing a column

inside a view,

when I browsed the view in sql developer editor, the column name spans two lines!!!...

putting it in one line fixed my problem.